# I can't seem to grab the inner most value of my object

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from an API using this exact link :
`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=XRP,ETH,BTC&tsyms=USD`

I put it in a variable like so:

`let XRPUSD = request.responseText;`

When I `console.log(XRPUSD)`, this variable gives me an object of (correct me if my term of object is wrong)
`{"XRP":{"USD":1.08},"ETH":{"USD":921.49},"BTC":{"USD":11755.04}}`

I am trying to grab the USD value of each currency individually (e.g "XRP", "ETH" & "BTC")

The way I am trying to grab the "USD" value is like so:
`console.log(XRPUSD.XRP.USD);`

However I am getting an undefined variable. Can someone help me so that I can grab the value of "USD" for each individual currency?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.responseText` is probably raw text, not a JS object. Conveniently, it's probably JSON, which means it *looks* like an object (but isn't just yet).

You'll want to parse it before you can use it:

`const XRPUSD = JSON.parse(request.responseText);`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I will accept the answer when I am able to!